# RTMP_Connect0, failed to connect socket. 51

Tags: ios

i want to use live audio streaming with wowza server,

i have implement RTMP Client for do this, this working fine in ipv4 network, but when i switch my network ipv4 to ipv6 then i got error.

error is: **RTMP_Connect0, failed to connect socket. 51**

this error is coming on **RTMP_Connect(pPlayRtmp, NULL)**

any one have idea about this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To use IPv6 networking with your Wowza server, you would need to have these settings in place:

1. Your server supports IPv6 networking.
2. You have at least version 7 of Java installed (recommend using the JVM that comes with the Wowza installation, which should be version 8 as of Wowza 4.5).
3. You've changed the following configuration files on your Wowza installation path.

For Linux, open the file [WowzaInstallPath]/bin/setenv.sh and set the following line to false

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false"
```

For Windows, use the file [WowzaInstallPath]\bin\setenv.bat

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false
```

Test streaming by using the following URL in an RTMP player:

```
rtmp://[::1]/vod/mp4:sample.mp4
```